# how to be sure that two directories are not subdirectories to each other (BASH)

Tags: bash, subdirectory

**EDITED:** this is more or less what I came up after @Mechanical's nice input. Any insight?

```
#!/bin/bash

path1="$(readlink -e "$1")"
path2="$(readlink -e "$2")"

EBADARGS=65

function checkArgsNumber()
{
    if test "$#" -ne 2; then
        echo "ERRORE: this script takes exactly 2 params."  
        exit $EBADARGS
    fi
}

function checkExistence()
{
    if [ ! -d $path1 ]; then
        echo  "ERROR: "$1" does not exist"
        exit $EBADARGS
    elif [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
        echo  "ERROR: "$2" does not exist"
        exit $EBADARGS
    elif [[ -L $path1 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: path1 can't be a symbolic link"
        exit $EBADARGS
    elif [[ -L $2 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: path2 can't be a symbolic  link"
        exit $EBADARGS
    fi
}

function checkIfSame()
{
    if [[ $path1 == $path2 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: path1 and path2 must be different directories"
        exit $EBADARGS     
    fi   
}

function checkIfSubdirectories()
{
    if [[ $path1 = *$path2* ]]; then
        echo "ERROR:"$1" is a $path2 subdirectory"
        exit $EBADARGS
    elif [[ $path2 = *$path1* ]]; then
        echo "ERROR:"$2" is a  $path1 subdirectory"
        exit $EBADARGS
    elif [[ -e "$(find $path1 -samefile $path2)" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR:"$(find $path1 -samefile $path2 -print0)" and "$2" have the same inode, $path2 is a  $path1 subdirectory"
        exit $EBADARGS
    elif [[ -e "$(find $path2 -samefile $path1)" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR:"$(find $path2 -samefile $path1 -print0)" and "$2" have the same inode,  $path1 is a  $path2 subdirectory"
        exit $EBADARGS
    fi
}

checkArgsNumber "$@"
checkExistence "$@"
checkIfSame "$@"
checkIfSubdirectories "$@"
```

now.. this should work and I hope it is useful somehow.
Could someone explain me how the `*$path2*` part works? What is the name of this `* *` operator? Where should I go read about it?

Comment: also, should I use == or a single = is OK ???? what is the difference?

Comment: in the `bash` manpage, under "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS", `string1 == string2` and `string1 = string2` seem to be listed as equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems:

## Stylistic

You should probably quote the entire argument to echo, as

```
    echo "ERROR: $1 is a subdirectory of $(readlink -e "$2")"
```

Without the quotes around the argument to `echo`, you are technically passing each word as its own parameter: `echo "ERROR:somedir" "is" "a" "subdirectory"`.... Since `echo` prints its parameters in the order given, separated by spaces, the output is the same in your case. But semantically it's not what you want.

(An example where it would be different:

```
echo foo          bar
```

would print `foo bar`.)

## Error message doesn't work properly

### If the arguments don't exist

```
$ ./check.sh nonexistent1 nonexistent2
ERROR:nonexistent1 is a subdirectory of
```

Obviously, this is irrelevant if you've already checked they exist.

You similarly need to check for corner cases such as where the parameters refer to the same directory:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ ln -s ../a b/c
$ ./check.sh a b/c
ERROR:a is a subdirectory of /dev/shm/a
```

## Doesn't detect symbolic links

```
$ mkdir a b
$ ln -s ../a b/c
$ ./check.sh a b
```

gives no error message.

## Doesn't detect `mount --bind`

```
$ mkdir a b b/c
$ sudo mount --bind a b/c
$ ./check.sh a b
```

gives no error message.

Comment: thanks @Mechanical :) I did "test -d..." and checked if they were different folders in other functions before getting to this one so (I think) all the cases you brought up have been covered in my real function. Nonetheless, those are important things that are missing in my example function. The stylistic point has any purpose outside from style? I'm definitely adopting it and I didn't use quotes before because most of the examples I saw were like this. "Printing" with no quotes is just ugly :)

Comment: Edited my answer to explain more about "echo".

Comment: mount --bind is a super fail in my script :) thanks!!
test -d, -h, -L can't seem to help in this.. any suggestion??

Comment: edited my question so all the corner cases seem to be covered. tnx @Mechanical !